# Two UITableViewControllers and One UISearchDisplay

Tags: iphone

I'm new to iPhone programming and is faced with a task to show data on of Books where the first table view shows the books in my library using the title of the book to sort and another table view to show the authors. There is a need to have a search bar on both of the table views and when used to search will show results categorized as certain results is returned according to the author and the others returned according to the title. Something similar to the search results returned by the iPod App.

Thanks in advance to all who can shed light.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, it sounds like you need to organize this somehow.  I recommend you try a tabbed-based application.  Create three tabs with the first two having navigation controllers for your tables. The first tab will have the tableView that sorts by book title.  The second tab will have the tableView that sorts by the author.  The third tab can do the search for either case.  Hopefully, that points you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but im afraid this is not an option for the requirements needs the searchbar be on top of the table views.